# Parsing commented tags with Jsoup HTML Parser

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing a Simple HTML Document with basic parser program.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(responseFromServer);

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
String linkText = null;
for (Element link : links) {      
  linkText = link.text();
}
```

Some of tags are commented out. I also want to parse those tags inside comment. As i don't have access to HTML Ouput source i cannot edit files and remove comments.

How can i parse comments tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup ignores comments by default. To get them parsed you could transform the html string before parsing. something along the lines

```
 htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("<!--|-->","");
 document doc = Jsoup.parser(htmlStr);
```

This will only work without problems if the commented out html is really more or less valid HTML. If it is just text you may need to transform this differently.